# Systrace | Android | No such file or directory

Tags: android, python, android-sdk-tools

I am unable to get systrace to work on my Mac. I am using a Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Beans. I have show traces enabled from the developer options. And in the terminal when I try to execute: ./systrace.py I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./systrace.py", line 212, in <module>
main()
File "./systrace.py", line 121, in main
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",    line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am not familiar with Python at all so I may be making a novice mistake. Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it looks like the script assumes adb is in your path. add the platform-tools sdk dir to your path and it should work.

Comment: "add the platform-tools sdk dir to your path" <- how do it do that ? I am just typing in "./systrace.py".

Comment: Got it ! Sorry for asking the dumbest question ever in the comment above ! Thanks

Comment: I had the same mystifying issue and I can confirm it was due to adb not being in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Systrace is not shipped as part of platform tools recently. Please user perfe[enter link description here](https://perfetto.dev/)tto instead

Answer (score -1):

Try doing adb root before running the script.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "doing adb root"?