# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory running 2 pipes

Tags: python, pipe

I want to execute multiple commands in shell . So i choose pipe to do it as i have to run all commands in a sequence to one shell .

I am already having one pipe in which I run the command , now I want to create another pipe to execute commands ,  when I try to do , python give me error at this line

```
self.__subprocess = Popen(self._command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your system can't find the file `self._command` is set to. Try adding the full path and see if that resolves it.

It has nothing to do with the pipes.

Comment: thanks for the reply ,i even replace the self._command with list but it didnt work . Now i have 2 classes ,each class has same code for executing multiple commands , object of first class work but when i run second class object it gives me that error , even if i both classes has same code it gives me that error

Comment: @kjnupp thanks for the reply , its strange on other file when i write the whole path of that exe than its works

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same error here:

[Systrace | Android | No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823007/systrace-android-no-such-file-or-directory)

I solved it via putting the path of "adb" into $PATH environment variable.