# Systrace error - No such file or directory

Tags: android, python, performance

I added adb to the path but the error persists.
I am trying to use systrace on a linux machine.
Kindly help me out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "systrace.py", line 152, in main
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What command did you used to add adb to the path?

Comment: I used export PATH=$PATH:/directory-containing-adb

Answer (score 0):

I think you added the path of adb instead of the path of the directory that containing adb.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851028/2225682 .

Answer (score 0):

Several possible reasons:

- You don't have **adb dir** in your path ()
- You don't have **Python** in your path
- Phone needs to **support** sysTrace and it seems that some of them just don't (pretty often we forget this :S)